# Why does Jquery .attr() not work on my object in IE 7 / 8?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have this very peculiar IE issue where the .attr() function will not select anything.

```
var tabID = $(selectedTab).attr('id');
```

selectedTab is a variable passed from an onclick method of a div like below:

```
<div id="WhatisaDog" onclick="handleSelectedTab(this);" class="tab tabPassive"></div>
```

The issue I am seeing in the IE developer tools javascript console is that when IE gets to the .attr() function, it does not return the id value. At that point the value of selectedTab (a variable holding a jqueryselector) is "#whatisaDog.tab". Shouldn't .attr('id') return "WhatisaDog" ? It works in firefox and chrome just not IE.

any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT:** here is a lot more of the code. The idea here is that I have several tabs on a page and want to show certain content depending on which tab was clicked. yes I know about jquery-ui's wonderful tabs functionality but I am not using it because it does not work in this way.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#DidYouKnow p.tabtextPassive a').append("?");
    var URL = document.URL;
    var params = URL.split("#");
    var tabToLoad = "#" + params[1];
    $(".articleContent").hide();
    if (params[1] != undefined) {
        handleSelectedTab($(tabToLoad +'.tab'));
    }
    else {
        handleSelectedTab($('.tab').first());
    }
});

function handleSelectedTab(selectedTab) {

    $('.tabLeft').removeClass('leftActive').addClass('leftPassive');
    $('.tabRight').removeClass('rightActive').addClass('rightPassive');
    $('.tab').removeClass('tabActive').addClass('tabPassive');
    $('.articleTabFormat p').removeClass('tabTextActive').addClass('tabTextPassive');

    $('.articleContent').hide();

    $(selectedTab).prev().removeClass('leftPassive').addClass('leftActive');
    $(selectedTab).removeClass('tabPassive').addClass('tabActive');
    $(selectedTab).next().removeClass('rightPassive').addClass('rightActive');
    $(selectedTab).children('p').removeClass('tabTextPassive').addClass('tabTextActive');

    var tabID = $(selectedTab).attr('id');
    loadSelectedBodyArea(tabID);
}

function loadSelectedBodyArea(areaID) {

    if (areaID == 'Maps') {
    }
    else if (areaID == 'Flags') {
    }
    else if (areaID == '') {
    }
    else {
        $('#'+ areaID +'.articleContent').show();
    }
}
```

and here is some of the html:

```
<div id="tabArea"> 
    <div class="articleTabsHolder">
        <div class="articleTabFormat">
            <div id="WhatisaHamster" class="tabLeft leftPassive"> </div>
            <div id="WhatisaHamster" onclick="handleSelectedTab(this);" class="tab tabPassive">
                <p class="tabTextPassive" style="padding-top:10px;">
                    <a href="#WhatisaHamster">What is a Hamster?</a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div id="WhatisaHamster" class="tabRight rightPassive"> </div></div>
        <div class="articleTabFormat">
            <div id="FactFile" class="tabLeft leftPassive"> </div>
            <div id="FactFile" onclick="handleSelectedTab(this);" class="tab tabPassive">
                <p class="tabTextPassive" style="padding-top:10px;">
                    <a href="#FactFile">Fact File</a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div id="FactFile" class="tabRight rightPassive"> </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="WhatisaHamster" class="articleContent"> </div>
        <div id="FactFile" class="articleContent"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any errors? What does it return, instead? Have you confirmed that `selectedTab` holds the value you expect?

Comment: no errors. selectedTab has the value in it but the .attr('id') line does not return anything at all. the var tabID remains undefined.

Comment: That code works fine for me on a test page in IE8. I think perhaps you should show us a little more of your Javascript code.

Comment: One thing: try `alert($(selectedTab).length)` to see if your selector is working the way you think it is.

Comment: I've edited it to show some more of the code and the html. The overarching issue that I have is that in IE the .show() functionality does not seem to occur when the tabs are clicked, but it works fine in EVERY other browser.

Comment: You can't expect anything to work properly on a page where the same "id" value appears on multiple elements. The "id" attribute for an element has to have a value that is unique on the entire page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
handleSelectedTab(this);
```

Why not pass the ID to the function so it is immediately available

```
handleSelectedTab($(this).attr('id'));
```

Depending on what you are doing within the function it may work.

**UPDATE**: See comment below regarding unique IDs.

Comment: I see that you have multiple divs with the same id.  Try making them all unique.

Comment: I've rewritten all of the functions to work this way and it hasn't fixed the issue, pretty bummed.

Comment: AHA! I decided to just start rewriting it all from scratch and using completely unique ids and that fixed it. It now works in IE and Firefox and Chrome and Opera. Thanks! (moral of the story, always use unique ids.) mcnarya, if you put in an answer I can give you credit for it.